# JFileChooser questions

Tags: java, save, jfilechooser

I know there is a way to make it so that the file you choose can only be a specific kind, but at the moment, I don't know how. Could someone please specify this please? BTW I know it involves the field FILES_ONLY or something like that. I couldn't find anything in the Javadoc, so I must be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I now know that you use `chooser.setSelectionMode(JFileChooser.whatever);` so I feel stupid now...

Comment: *so I feel stupid now* welcome to the world of programming ;)

Comment: I started with Java, I think I'll be able to float through unless I start Objective-C or something :D